# Form with multiple different ids, how to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Don't know how to save a question form that will have 2 ids, event id and user id

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers
end
```

Event.rb

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end
```

Question.rb

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

Answer.rb

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question

  scope :sorted, ->{ order(created_at: :asc) }
end
```

questions_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @question = current_user.questions.build
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    @question["user_id"] = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I have the standard form generated with the scaffold, but I cant piece together what I am missing from my limited knowledge and experience in rails on how to get every question that a user makes to be linked to a specific created event and show which user created that particular question (I would assume that each question entry will need a user_id and a event_id column)

```
<%= form_with(model: question, local: true) do |form| %> 
  <%= form.label :body %> 
  <%= form.rich_text_area :body %> 
  <%= form.submit 'Create Question' %> 
<% end %>
```

Updated for Error:

When I try to create a question, each entry requires an `event_id` (an event has many questions) and a `user_id` (I want to show who created that question).

Are my models and controllers setup correctly? When I try to create a question for an event, the error "Event must exist" occurs

Updated with ERD pic ( Not sure if I should just have users or seperate into creators and users )

[ERD after reading up on last update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFi6h.jpg)
I begun reading up more on data modelling and I came up with this ERD...I am still not very sure on achieving 3NF and setting up the relationships, and how to translate it to rails models but would be great to have comments on my ERD so I can learn.

Creator creates events that users can join. Creator creates questions that users can post answers. Each event has many questions and each question can have many answers.

Comment: Do you know how you would represent this with a standard data model? Forget Rails for a moment and think about a standard relational database would look like. Draw out what each table looks like in terms of columns and relationships. If you can do that, then maybe update your question with this information. That will help you understand what you are trying to achieve, then ask smaller questions about the parts of Rails that you can't work out how to map back to your model.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Should the event be selected in the form? Could you add code of the form please? And `question_params` method from questions_controller

Comment: Should user be able to select event through the form?

Comment: No. The user admin can create an event but at the question creation page and form, how do I make it such that the question is automatically created with the event saved? 

Event (Created by admin) > Questions (Created by admin) > Answers (Created by all users)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need [nested resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) to achieve your goal. It means, that questions are nested inside events, like 'parent' event has 'children' questions. At first, change your routes:

```
resources :events do
  resources :questions
end
```

Run `rake routes` in terminal and you will see new routes with `:event_id` parameter. Now on events#index you can add `link_to 'Questions about this event', event_questions_path(event)` near each event, the link will lead you to `events/1/questions` (1 is id of the event). In QuestionsController you have new parameter, `event_id`, which you can use to find needed Event or to assign as foreign key.

Change you form

```
<%= form_with(model: [@event, @question], local: true) do |form| %> 
  <%= form.label :body %> 
  <%= form.rich_text_area :body %> 
  <%= form.submit 'Create Question' %> 
<% end %>
```

and controller a bit to work with nested routes

```
  def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @question = event.questions.build
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @question = event.questions.build(question_params)
    @question.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Also, you should remove the line `accepts_nested_attributes_for` from Event and Question models, since you never use it

Comment: Is it possible for the form to auto populate the event_id?
As in as an admin user, I can create a question from the new question form after selecting an event.
I would like the current event id to be automatically saved when I submit a new question. I would guess that I need to create an instance of current_event somewhere to be able to let rails know that when submitting the new question form it is for the event that was selected?

Comment: What do you mean "after selecting an even"? Where and how you want to select it?

Comment: Like in the index page of events, there will be a link that the user is able to click that will bring them to the index page of questions, and then the user can click on a link in the index page of questions to create a new question. I am not sure now if rails automatically knows that the new question created is linked to the event or do I have to manually save the event_id via the code you shared. Or is there a way to automatically include the event_id via a hidden_field which brings me to initial question of how to automatically include the correct and current event_id.